# How to output ampersand (&) from XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm converting all `&` into `&amp;` in my XML so that the XSLT will compile.  I'm styling the XML into HTML.  However when a textbox is populated by the XSLT, I need the `&amp;` to display as `&`.

For example, it shows "`you &amp; me`" in the text box, but I need to see "`you & me`".

Comment: textbox, as in `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 14):

### How to output `&amp;` as `&` in XSLT

In general, here are alternative techniques for outputting `&amp;` as `&`:

- Globally:

  ```
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  or
  <xsl:output method="text"/>`
  ```
- For ampersands originating from XSLT:

  ```
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&]]></xsl:text>
  ```
- For ampersands originating from input XML:

  ```
  <xsl:value-of select="XPATH EXPRESSION" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  ```

---

Now, in your specific case you say that `&amp;`s within text boxes are being displayed as "`&amp;`".   I don't see that at all.  Apart from XML or XSLT, in which I show above how to generate `&` rather than `&amp;`, HTML itself really has no problem with `&amp;`...

Consider this simple test HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h3>No &amp;amp; is displayed in any of these cases:</h3>
    <div>
      In an input box:
      <input type="text" value="Ampersand: &amp;"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      In a text area:
      <textarea>Ampersand: &amp;</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>In a div: Ampersand: &amp;</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This renders in browsers as follows:

[image]

As you can see, there is no problem rendering `&amp;` as `&`.

Comment: I have expanded the above answer to address your follow-ups.

Comment: Creating a variable as the following and appending it to my link worked for me: 
 <xsl:variable name="variablesSeparator"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&]]></xsl:text>
            </xsl:variable>

Answer (score 4):

In many situations `&#38;` will work very well. It's valid xsl, understood also by the browser. XSL, some-one-still-loves-youuuuuuuuu.