# Escape special characters after applying XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

When I get special characters in my xml the XSL transform throws error. For instance the transformation errors because of ***&***. How to escape special characters and apply it as a template to the entire file rather than do it for each node as there might special characters in any field and the characters could different.

```
 <xsl:template match="node()">
  <t> &quot; &apos; &lt; &amp; &gt;</t>
 </xsl:template>
```

> Chiéf Executive Officér & Operating Officér

**XML:**

```
<ad:Sale_Data xmlns:ad="urn:com.ad.report/saleslead">
<ad:Sale_Tx_Entry>
    <ad:name>prominent sale</ad:name>
    <ad:businessID>209320484</ad:businessID>
    <ad:Lead_Organization ad:Descriptor="Chiéf Executive Officér & Operating Officér">
        <ad:ID ad:type="AID">sadlksalfkdki23i204urfdfmd9mdscdkhytt</ad:ID>
        <ad:ID ad:type="Business_Model_Sale_Ref_ID">475846759</ad:ID>
    </ad:Lead_Organization>
    <ad:Management_Hierarchy>
        <ad:Lead_Organization_ID>475847049</ad:Lead_Organization_ID>
    </ad:Management_Hierarchy>
    <ad:storemanager ad:Descriptor="J Loews">
        <ad:ID ad:type="AID">sadlksalfkdki23i204urfdfmd9mdscdkhytt</ad:ID>
        <ad:ID ad:type="S_ID">754954</ad:ID>
    </ad:storemanager>
    <ad:SalePerson>
        <ad:Sale_Ref_ID>3457578</ad:Sale_Ref_ID>
        <ad:Sale_Profile ad:Descriptor="Sale Person1">
            <ad:ID ad:type="AID">sadlksalfkdki23i204fdfmd9mdscdkhytt</ad:ID>
            <ad:ID ad:type="Sale_Tx_ID">475847</ad:ID>
        </ad:Sale_Profile>
        <ad:Business_Model ad:Descriptor="3457578 Sale Person1 - Business Development Leader1">
            <ad:ID ad:type="AID">sadlksalfkdki23i204urfdfmd9mdscdkhytt</ad:ID>
        </ad:Business_Model>
        <ad:SalePerson ad:Descriptor="Business Development Leader1">
            <ad:ID ad:type="AID">sadlksalfkdki23i204urfdfmd9mdscdkhytt</ad:ID>
            <ad:ID ad:type="S_ID">4782</ad:ID>
        </ad:SalePerson>
        <ad:StoreManager ad:Descriptor="J Loews">
            <ad:ID ad:type="AID">sadlksalfkdki23i204urfdfmd9mdscdkhytt</ad:ID>
            <ad:ID ad:type="S_ID">754954</ad:ID>
        </ad:StoreManager>
    </ad:SalePerson>
    <ad:SalePerson>
        <ad:Sale_Ref_ID>3457579</ad:Sale_Ref_ID>
        <ad:Sale_Profile ad:Descriptor="Sale Person2">
            <ad:ID ad:type="AID">sadlksalfkdki23i204urfdfmd9mdscdkhytt</ad:ID>
            <ad:ID ad:type="Sale_Tx_ID">918328</ad:ID>
        </ad:Sale_Profile>
        <ad:Business_Model ad:Descriptor="3457579 Sale Person2 - Business Development Leader2">
            <ad:ID ad:type="AID">sadlksalfkdki23i204urfdfmd9mdscdkhytt</ad:ID>
        </ad:Business_Model>
        <ad:SalePerson ad:Descriptor="Business Development Leader2">
            <ad:ID ad:type="AID">sadlksalfkdki23i204urfdfmd9mdscdkhytt</ad:ID>
            <ad:ID ad:type="S_ID">487548</ad:ID>
        </ad:SalePerson>
        <ad:StoreManager ad:Descriptor="J Loews">
            <ad:ID ad:type="AID">sadlksalfkdki23i204urfdfmd9mdscdkhytt</ad:ID>
            <ad:ID ad:type="S_ID">754954</ad:ID>
        </ad:StoreManager>
    </ad:SalePerson>
</ad:Sale_Tx_Entry>
</ad:Sale_Data>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ad="urn:com.ad.report/saleslead">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/ad:Sale_Data">
        <xsl:text>"BusinessName"|"BusinessCode"|"BusinessStructure"|"BusinessStructureID"|"BusinessStructureManager"|"StoreID"|"SaleProfile"|"BusinessModel"|"SalePerson"|"StoreManager"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ad:Sale_Tx_Entry/ad:SalePerson"/>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ad:SalePerson">
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ad:Sale_Tx_Entry/ad:name"/> 
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ad:Sale_Tx_Entry/ad:businessID"/> 
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ad:Sale_Tx_Entry/ad:Lead_Organization/@ad:Descriptor"/> 
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ad:Sale_Tx_Entry/ad:Management_Hierarchy/ad:Lead_Organization_ID"/> 
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ad:Sale_Tx_Entry/ad:storemanager/@ad:Descriptor"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ad:Sale_Ref_ID"/>  
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ad:Sale_Profile/@ad:Descriptor"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ad:Business_Model/@ad:Descriptor"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ad:SalePerson/@ad:Descriptor"/> 
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ad:StoreManager/@ad:Descriptor"/> 
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Some "special characters" are more special than others. If your input contains an unescaped ampersand character (as does your example) then it's not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437121/how-to-output-ampersand-from-xslt - This may be the solution you are searching for.

Comment: Thank you all for your response. I will have the source fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> When I get special characters in my xml the XSL transform throws
>   error. For instance the transformation errors because of &.

The XSLT transformation is throwing an error because the input is not well-formed XML. XSLT requires well-formed XML as input. (Don't think of this as "XML containing special characters", think of it as non-XML.)

> How to escape special characters

An ampersand in XML must always be escaped as `&amp;`. If you are getting input in which it has not been properly escaped, you should trace it to whatever is generating the broken XML and fix it at source. Repairing it later is never going to be satisfactory, because there's no foolproof way of distinguishing an `&` used with its special XML meaning from an `&` in text that should have been escaped.